# Boot sector for a floppy disk with FAT12 filesystem

Tags: assembly, filesystems, x86, nasm

I'm writing a bootsector for a `FAT12` file system on a 1.44MB floppy disk using `nasm x86 assembly`. When computer boots from this floppy disk to real mode, its bootsector will load a second stage file, ex. *STAGE2.SYS*, for simplicity, *STAGE2.SYS* is a bin file. Anyone know an example bootsector which is written in `nasm x86 assembly` that do exactly what i described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the one [here](http://alexfru.narod.ru/os/fat/fat.html), in the zip's '_boot' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link which will help you EXACTLY on what you are looking for:

www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevIndex.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the MikeOS bootloader.
You can find it here: http://github.com/mig-hub/mikeOS/blob/master/source/bootload/bootload.asm

You'll just have to change the kernel name in the data section:

```
kern_filename   db "KERNEL  BIN"
```

To:

```
kern_filename   db "STAGE2  BIN"
```

Don't forget that FAT12 has file names in the 8.3 format!